# What keeps an object from getting disposed? / Does asynchronous flow keeps object alive?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, garbage-collection

Consider the following code:

```
public class ChainHandler
{
    public void ProcessTopUp(string amount, string phone, ResponseCallback responseCallback)
    {
        var statebag = GetStateBag();

        ICommand basecommand = new BlmLoginCommand(statebag);
        basecommand .SetNext(new BlmDynamicCommand(statebag, RequestMessageEvent.TCD_RecargaTAE10, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "amt", amount }, { "cel", phone } }))
               .SetNext(new BlmDynamicCommand(statebag, RequestMessageEvent.TCD_BuyProduct))
               .SetNext(new BlmEndCommand(statebag, responseCallback));

        basecommand.ExecuteAsync();
    }


}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChainHandler ch = new ChainHandler();

        ch.ProcessTopUp("5.00", "0123456789", OnProcessResponse);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnProcessResponse()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The method "ExecuteAsync" starts an asynchronous flow which uses the commands.
The commands using internally the Socket class asynchronously (Event-based Asynchronous Pattern).

The question is: Is it possible that the EndCommand is never reached because the object basecommand gets disposed after leaving the "ExecuteAsync" method?

Even .net knows that the EndCommand has a callback method?

Or is .net intelligent enough to keep the object alive until the asynchronous flow is finished?

In case the object does not stay alive what can i do to instruct the Garbage Collector to not to dispose basecommand?

Comment: GC is too smart to instruct it about anything. It'l keep your object alive as long as it is used by any code of your program

Comment: An object can become disposed if you are in an asynchronous Programmflow. Thats the reason why you get an object disposed Exception when in a async socket procedure a callback can't find anymore.

Comment: ... are you seeing an error in your code, or are you asking to have a confirmation? That said, Hans is right: it is very important to distinguish between "Disposed" and "collected". In the second case, the GC is smart enough, and nothing will be collected when it could still be used. This includes asynchronous execution, execution in a thread-pool etc. Again, Hans correctly points out that even if you don't see it, the compiler inserts code to pass references around, and this will keep objects live as long as needed.

Comment: ...in the first case, it depends, and it is totally in the hands of the framework you are using. Nothing forbids something somewhere to call Dispose on your BlmEndCommand before this has the chance to run and call the callback

Answer (score 3):

Accuracy is important here.  Objects do not get disposed automatically.  It is always done explicitly in your code, either by the *using* statement or calling the Dispose() method.  So there's never a problem if you don't dispose in your code.

What you probably meant to say was "garbage collected".  Which is very straight-forward in .NET, as long as the garbage collector can see a reference to an object, and that reference is held by another object that itself is alive, then an object won't be collected.

What however is not always that clear is where that reference is being stored.  The C# compiler can *rewrite* your code and move it from a method in your class to a method of a hidden class.  That hidden class has an unspeakable name and has a field that stores the reference.  Which the garbage collector can see, thus preventing the object from getting collected.  The technical term for copying the reference from your code into the field of that hidden class object is ["variable capturing"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/03/01/understanding-variable-capturing-in-c.aspx).

This code rewriting trick is used in lots of places in C#.  Originally implemented in the language to support anonymous methods and iterators.  And extended in later versions to implement lambda expressions and asynchronous methods.  A good way to see what is going on is by looking at the code that the C# compiler generates.  Visible with ildasm.exe or an imperfect decompiler.  This otherwise certainly fits the "intelligent enough" moniker.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, your command won't get disposed since it has a delegate/ callback reference. This means, you command object will be kept alive by the delegate, for as long as the delegate lives. Eventually, once after the callback is executed , the GC will pick untouched (objects that has no root) is dispose accordingly.

Updated:

Other scenario would be, what if there is no callback reference.

In such case, your object is non-eligible immediately for garbage collection since the EPM (pattern that you follow in your code) API keeps a reference to your request within the thread pool, specifically IO completion thread. This hint GC to not to touch or collected until it completes.

Comment: And if the callback delegate would not be there. If the whole flow would entirely be handled within Chainhandler. I am not sure if you are right with your assumption.

Comment: An object is considered alive and non-eligible for garbage collection if any live thread contains a reference to it, or if it's referenced statically (directly or indirectly in both cases).

In your examples the EPM API keeps a reference to your request (within the thread pool, specifically IO completion operations are lodged) and so it won't be garbage collected until it completes irrespective or whether it has the callback or not.

Comment: Ah. Thats a new information for me. Does this apply to all kinds of asynchronous patterns or only when IO completion port is involved.

Comment: All asynchronous operation are performed on IO completion port thread ( which is part of CLR thread pool). But the latest version of asynchronous operation using async/await uses more of a state machine. I don't know (completely) much about how async/await does the job when it come to memory management. So you can better seek external helps.